# Swift 4: Protocol how to define subclass type

Tags: swift, protocols

I have protocol define a function return self

```
public protocol DBObject {
   static func select(where condition:String?) -> Array<DBObject>?
}
```

then shop conform DBObject

```
public struct Shop:DBObject {

}


guard let array = Shop.select(where:nil) else{
      return
}
for shop in array {
  let _ = shop as! Shop
}
```

I know `array` always return `Array<Shop>`,but I don't know how to define like subClass type

like that:

```
static func select(where condition:String?) -> Array<conform.Type>?//Is there such a way?
```

What to do?

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Just use `Self` – `static func select(where condition: String?) -> [Self]?`

Comment: @Hamish It looks to solve my problem,but a build error `Protocol 'DBObject' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements` when I use Self,Can you help me? thank

Comment: @fidetro Yeah that's a current unfortunate limitation of the compiler; really `DBObject` *should* be usable as a type, as a return `[Self]` type can be covariant with `[DBObject]`. You can work around it either with a type eraser, or an underscored protocol with a version of the requirement that returns an array of protocol typed elements, for example: http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59f9c640ffc82470b5a63b04.